# What is Causing this STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION?

Tags: c++

I suck at c++ so i suspect it's a dumb mistake I have made. After a bit of research I see that that STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION happens when the program tries to access invalid memory blocks. That said I'm not seeing what is causing that to happen in the code below.

```
int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
Node* testNode = new Node("jhon","doe", 1, 80);
BraidedLinkedList* testList = new BraidedLinkedList();
testList->AddNode(testNode);
return 0;}
```

BraidedLinkedList.cpp

```
void BraidedLinkedList::AddNode(Node *newNode) {
if (this->start == NULL) {
    this->start = newNode;
    cout<<newNode->getInfo();
//the following line does not work either
    //cout<<this->start->getInfo()<<endl;
}
```

Node.cpp

```
const string& Node::getInfo() {
string returnString = "";
returnString += this->getFristName() + " ";
returnString += this->getLastName() + " ";
returnString += this->getId() + " ";
returnString += this->getGrade() + " ";
}
```

Comment: Well you don't actually return anything from `getInfo`?

Comment: You should invest in learning to use a debugger.You can single step each statement and *watch* the values of variables.

Comment: You don't need to use `this->` inside a method function.  Also, is your function actually named "getF**r**istName()` or should it be `getFirstName()`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg wow.. just wow can't believe I missed that. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Node::getInfo' method is returning a const reference to a temporary string object. At the point at which it attempts to print the string it's highly likely it could crash. I'm assuming you simply left out the return. In this scenario the return type should simply be 'string'.